# No implicit conversion of Array into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a simple method that sorts characters in a string and returns `true` if "b" is within three (or fewer) characters after an "a" and vice-versa.

Here it is below:

```
def near_ab(string)
  arr = string.split("")
  a_position = arr.each_with_index.select {|i| arr[i] == "a"}
  b_position = arr.each_with_index.select {|i| arr[i] == "b"}

  if a_position - b_position <= 3      #arr[a] - arr[b] == 3
     return true
 else 
     return false
 end
```

end

However, after running it I get the following error:

```
    `[]': no implicit conversion of Array into Integer (TypeError)
```

Why is it giving me this error and how should I approach resolving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) maps the second argument as the index.

Use this instead:

```
arr.each_with_index.select {|element, i| arr[i] == "a"}
```

---

A better way to accomplish what you want:

```
def near_ab(string)
  arr = string.split("")
  a_position = arr.index('a') # Array#index returns the index of the first element that match `'a'` in this case
  b_position = arr.index('b')

  if (a_position - b_position).abs <= 3      #arr[a] - arr[b] == 3
    return true
  else 
    return false
  end
end

near_ab('hallo, ich bin Jonas!') # => returns false
```

(you can copy-paste this in your console to try it out)

Comment: I get a new error after changing it to this:  undefined method `<=' for [["a", 1]]:Array (NoMethodError)

Comment: That's exactly the point: The "select" statement above returns an Array. It seems the "<=" method is not defined for Array Objects and BTW I assume that you don't want to compare the Arrays. If you really want to do it like this you may add a `map {|a| a[1]}`after the select statement: `arr.each_with_index.select {|element, i| arr[i] == "a"}.map{|a| a[1]}`

Comment: Huh. Forget the map. I just tried and it doesn't work as well. I'd really consider to do it in a different way. This all looks quite ugly. Sorry for the misleading comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `String#index` method?
`each_with_index` needs two arguments as already said. `select` provides you with an Array that you can't compare by simply using `<=`, and that's the reason for the error.

I'd use something like:

```
def near_ab(string)
     a_position = string.index('a')
     b_position = string.index('b')

    (a_position - b_position).abs <= 3·
end

puts near_ab('abcde')
puts near_ab('acdeb')
puts near_ab('acdefb')
```

BTW, I don't see any relation to Rails in your question.